# Is function $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ is always differentiable $\forall~ x \in $ domain of $f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is differentiable in it's domain?

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function, recreational-mathematics

I wanted a little help in proving or disproving the statement:
"The function $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ is always differentiable $\forall~ x \in $ domain of $f(x)$ $~\textbf{if}~$ $f(x)$ is differentiable in it's domain."

$\bullet~$ $\textbf{My approach:}$

I took some examples like $ e^{1/x} ,  e^{-1/x}, e^{{1}/{x^2}} ,e^{\sin(x)}$ and this statement holds true. I verified them using the first principle. I could not prove it for a general $f(x)$ but if its true then it will save a lot of time which would go to check functions like $g(x) =  e^{-1/(x+e) +1/(x-\pi)}$ so, is this statement true? kindly help me out.

Comment: Isn't this a special case of "If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $g$ at $f(x)$, then $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $x$ with $(g\circ f)'(x) = (g'\circ f)(x)\cdots f'(x)$"?

Comment: It might help apply @MushuNrek's observation if you wrote "$\exp(u)$" instead of $e^u$; that functional form makes it more obvious what's going on.

Comment: BTW, the name for what @MushuNrek observed is "the chain rule", if you need to look it up. Also, did you mean to put three dots there, "$\cdot \cdot \cdot$", instead of a simple multiplication sign?

Comment: Nope, no idea what happened there... It should be a multiplication sign, thx. @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: @MushuNrek: Sticky keyboard key??? Oh well, no biggie. Too bad comments get edit-locked.

Comment: @MushuNrek  yes,it may be a special case but I don't have much idea how to prove this

Comment: @Gingerbread the general proof is a bit awkward... How did show it for the examples and why doesn't your approach work for a general f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$. Formally, this means that the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\quad\text{ and }\quad \lim_{y\to f(x_0)} \dfrac{g(y) - g(f(x_0))}{y- f(x_0)}
$$
exist. Denote the limits by the usual $f'(x_0)$ and $g'(f(x_0))$. We need to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}
$$
exists and is equal to $(g'\circ f)(x_0)\cdot f'(x_0)$.

Intuitively (and naively), one would write for $x\neq x_0$ that
$$
\dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0} = \dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{f(x_0) - f(x)}\cdot\dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$
and it would suffice to take the limit of both products, because $f$ is necessarily continuous at $x_0$, hence $f(x)\to f(x_0)$ for $x\to x_0$. **BUT** it is possible that $f(x) = f(x_0)$ for $x\neq x_0$ if $f$ is not injectif. That means that the above doesn't work. And this is the reason why this proof is a bit annoying. So to work around this problem, we define
$$
h(x) := \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{f(x) - f(x_0)}&\text{ if $f(x) \neq f(x_0)$}\\
g'(f(x_0)) &\text{ if $f(x) = f(x_0)$}
\end{array}\right..
$$
Now, this function is well-defined (and we used the most "obvious" definition [if not clear, think about it; if still not clear, write a comment]). Furthermore, it is continuous at $x_0$ (clear? if not, prove it). And that still gives us the result we want, because
$$
\dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0} = h(x)\cdot \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \underset{x\to x_0}{\rightarrow} h(x_0)\cdot f'(x_0)
$$
and $h(x_0) = g'(f(x_0))$. (Clear, why the above equality holds?)

Comment: Nice explanation of the whats and whys of proving the chain rule. If this were Twitter I'd follow you based on this.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, I try my best!